# Jekyll cannot find gem after bundle install

Tags: jekyll

```
➜  site bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using ffi 1.9.14
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using sass 3.4.22
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.7
Using kramdown 1.12.0
Using liquid 3.0.6
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using rouge 1.11.1
Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
Using minima 1.1.0
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using rb-inotify 0.9.7
Using pathutil 0.14.0
Using jekyll-sass-converter 1.4.0
Using listen 3.0.8
Using jekyll-watch 1.5.0
Using jekyll 3.2.1
Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 18 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
➜  site bundle exec jekyll serve
Could not find minima-1.1.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

After bundle install Jekyll still complain missing `minima-1.1.0` gem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As seen on [Jekyll's home page](https://jekyllrb.com/), you have to do another bundle install from inside your site root.

```
gem install jekyll bundler 
jekyll new my-awesome-site 
cd my-awesome-site 
bundle install 
bundle exec jekyll serve
# => Now browse to http://localhost:4000
```

Comment: I was inside the project root (`/site`). I solved this issue using `gem install minima`.